# Capturing console log output from Firefox using Selenium webdriver python bindings

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

We have a webpage where it logs the output using `console.log()` method. I am trying to automate it using selenium webdriver Python bindings. I read about the "`driver.get_log('browser')`" and used it, but it only displays the JavaScript error messages and does not obtain the actual output logged in the console.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities   
d = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=d,firefox_profile=fp)
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print entry
```

I do not want the error logs in console. I want the actual output of the webpage displayed in browser console.

Comment: what you mean `actual output of the webpage` ? And why you want to see it in browser console? Do you actually know purpose of browser console?

Comment: I mean the output logged from javascript. For example pls refer,
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_output_console

Here output 11 will be logged in the console, and is there a way to read the output logged (11 in this case) using selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known bug in Selenium and/or Firefox. See issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1161

It seems to work fine for the Chrome driver, if it helps anyone.